# How to use Visual Source Safe with file names in Russian Language?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005, vssettings

I still use microsoft visual source safe 2005, for sql server, #c and any other subject I work with.

Recently I started to study Russian Language.

I would like to add a file called "Спрашивать.txt" to my source safe.

When I try to add it, I get the error message you can see on the picture below.
I could not find any way around it.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Russian as the [current Language for non-Unicode programs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_select_language_version.mspx?mfr=true) on your machine and try again.